# Is the java-io tag being abused?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, abuse

The ['java-io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-io) has 44 questions (when I left the page to ask this question - the tools listed 25 uses for the new tag).  The questions are mostly not new.

I didn't immediately see a question where the tag was inappropriate, but it did occur to me that someone might be farming themselves a 'Taxonomist' badge.

Could someone check who is doing the tagging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the result of [a retag that I did yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58198/please-merge-these-java-tags).  I don't show up in the edit history for most of them because I used a ♦-moderator-only tag merging tool.  I had to create the tag in order to use the tool, so I do show up once as an editor.  I already have the `Taxonomist` badge on SO, so another one won't be awarded for that tag.

Comment: So, in summary, the answer to my question is "No, it is not being abused".  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not check for yourself? Just look at the edit histories for the questions.

Taking a small random sample shows them to be either part of the original set of tags set by the asker, or a fix/addition by a random other person (so far never the same one).